# python pandas add multiple columns not existing in another list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe whose column names are a subset of the index values of another dataframe.

I would like to add to the initial dataframe empty columns that exists in the second index but do not exist as column names in the first. I have solved this using the following loop but wonder is there a smarter way to do this using, for example, `assign` or `append(axis=1)`?

My example below with the output it produces (the correct desired result)

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
df_matrix = pd.DataFrame([(1, 2),
                   (3, 4)],
                  index=[['a','b']],
                  columns=('value_1','value_3'))
```

`df_matrix`

|  | value_1 | value_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 4 |

```
df_column = pd.DataFrame({'value':[11, 22, 33, 44]}, index=['value_1','value_2','value_3','value_4'])
```

`df_column`

|  | value |
| --- | --- |
| value_1 | 11 |
| value_2 | 22 |
| value_3 | 33 |
| value_4 | 44 |

```
for index, row in df_column.iterrows():
    if index not in df_matrix.columns:
        df_matrix[index]=0
```

updated `df_matrix`

|  | value_1 | value_3 | value_2 | value_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| b | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Are you sure those are the column names you want in the final output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would essentially do what you want without the loop.

```
df_matrix[[x for x in df_column.index if x not in df_matrix.columns]] = 0

 value_1  value_3   value_2 value_4
a   1          2        0      0
b   3          4        0      0
```

Comment: Doing this with larger datasets, I got: PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
  self[col] = value